# configuring nodes for Jenkins build slaves with docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I've configured my Jenkins master to use docker and I can connect to docker, I've got a simple pipeline to test this:

```
node ('docker-build-slave') {
    stage ('On slave') {
        sh 'ls -l'
        sh 'uname -a'
    }
}
```

When I instigate a build and look at whats being written to the console, I get:

> Started by user chris adkin
>   [Pipeline] node
>   Still waiting to schedule task
>   All nodes of label ‘docker-build-slave’ are offline

and it just hangs, I'm wondering if there is something really obvious I ave missed, do I need to create a node for my docker build slaves ?.

If I go onto the machine hosting jenkins, I can see that the build slave container have been started.

Answer (score 1):

The `docker-build-slave` that you supply is a label filtering the available Jenkins agents (master/slaves). If you do not have this label assigned either to the master or to any of the (available) slaves, this job cannot be built. Read more about [labels](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Usinglabels)

To let Jenkins pipeline, use the `docker` global variable, e.g. as described in [this example](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#advanced-usage-with-scripted-pipeline):

```java
node {
    checkout scm
    /*
     * In order to communicate with the MySQL server, this Pipeline explicitly
     * maps the port (`3306`) to a known port on the host machine.
     */
    docker.image('mysql:5').withRun('-e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw" -p 3306:3306') { c ->
        /* Run some tests which require MySQL */
        sh 'make check'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging around, and I am a bit shame faced to answer my own question, I came across this Jenkins article:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44859

I built my image using the Java JDK 7, the article states, and I quote from the comment added by Vinson Lee:

Jenkins 2.54+ requires Java 8.

I modified the docker file for my image to install open jdk 8 and everything is now working.

Comment: I cannot really believe this. At least this won't help you to run above commands in a docker container.

Comment: The problem for the solution you described should be reflected in the logs for the slave under _Manage Nodes_ in Jenkins Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `node {}` with a specific `label`, and don't have any nodes with that label set-up, the build will be stuck forever, as mentioned by [StephenKings answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46542647/289064). You also need to make sure you have at least 2 executors set-up when using a single node (like `'master'`), otherwise pipeline builds will usually be stuck, as they consist of a root build and several sub-builds for the steps.

Answer (score -1):

The fix worked, this is the console output from successfully running the build job:

```
Started by user chris adkin
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
All nodes of label ‘docker-build-slave’ are offline
Running on docker-13b5a18eb067 in /home/jenkins/workspace/Pipeline With Docker Slave
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (On slave)
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline With Docker Slave] Running shell script
+ ls -l
total 0
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline With Docker Slave] Running shell script
+ uname -a
Linux localhost 4.9.49-moby #1 SMP Wed Sep 27 00:36:29 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```